# Add multilevel headers to table

Tags: html, html-table

I am new to HTML. I have a table like this:

[image: example]

I would like to convert this image to a html table. I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>value</td>
    <td>value</td>
    <td>value</td>
    <td>value</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>value</td>
    <td><table width="350" border="1">
    <tr>
    <td>
    <table>
    <tr><td>value</td></tr>
    <tr><td>value<br>value <br>value<br>value<br></td></tr>
    </table>
    </td>
    <td>value</td>
    <td>value</td>
    <td>value</td>
    <td>value</td>
    </tr>
    </table></td>
    <td>
    <table width="100" border="1">
    <tr>
    <td>value</td>
    <td>value</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </td>
    <td>
    <table width="100" border="1">
    <tr>
    <td>value</td>
    <td>value</td>
    </tr>
    </table></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>value</td>
    <td>value</td>
    <td>value</td>
    <td>value</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>value</td>
    <td>value</td>
    <td>value</td>
    <td>value</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>value</td>
    <td>value</td>
    <td>value</td>
    <td>value</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: use [colspan](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_table_colspan_rowspan.asp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `colspan` attribute on your `th` elements:

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Title 1</th>
    <th colspan="2">Title 2</th>
    <th>Title 3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Subtitle 1.1</td>
    <td>Subtitle 2.1</td>
    <td>Subtitle 2.2</td>
    <td>Subtitle 3.1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1.1 value</td>
    <td>2.1 value</td>
    <td>2.2 value</td>
    <td>3.1 value</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You can read more about the `table` HTML element [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table).